# Optimising profit from a three way bet

Tags: probability, optimization, game-theory, gambling

Suppose I have teams A and B playing each other. The odds on A to win are $2/5$, odds on B to win are $6/1$ and odds for a draw are $11/4$.

Suppose I have $x$ total amount of money. In what proportion should I divide $x$ in bets on every possible outcome (team A winning, team B winning, and a draw), in order to ensure that I $\textbf{always}$ obtain an overall profit?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how this way of writing odds work: If I have $5$ money, and I bet it all on $A$, and then $A$ win, will I walk away with $5+2 = 7$ money?

Comment: Yes, that's right @Arthur

Comment: Are your numbers right? If I have understood the way you are quoting the odds, a winning bet of $a$ on $A$ to win will return $\frac 75 a$, yes?  But, if so, suppose I have $1$ to invest and divide it amongst the three bets as $(a,b,c)$ with $a+b+c=1$.  Then in order to be profitable if $a$ wins I need $\frac 75a >1\implies a>\frac 57$.  Similarly we need $b>\frac 17$ and $c>\frac 4{15}$.  Alas, $\frac 57 +\frac 17+\frac 4{15}>1$.

Comment: Ah, I see - it was a hypothetical scenario @lulu

Answer (score 1):

If you bet $\frac{5x}7$ on $A$ and the rest on $B$ or draw, and $A$ wins, then if $A$ wins you break even. If you bet $\frac x7$ on $B$ and the rest on $A$ or draw, and $B$ wins, you break even. If you bet $\frac{4x}{15}$ on draw and the rest on $A$ and $B$, and there is a draw, you break even.

That means, if you want to be guaranteed to walk away with $x$ money no matter what, you need to bet a total of $\frac{5x}7 + \frac{x}{7} + \frac{4x}{15} = \frac{118x}{105}$ money.

Comment: In other words, it is not possible to be profitable in this scenario @Arthur

Comment: @Alex It's not possible to _guarantee_ a profit, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how these odds are given, it appears that there's a substantial "vig" protecting the house from losing money. Therefore, it's mathematically impossible to bet in a way that guarantees you profit. Now, the only way that changes is if you know what the true probabilities of win, lose and draw are. Of course, no one ever knows these probabilities but they can be estimated. The house usually does this better than 99% of gamblers though.

If you were really confident that you knew the probabilities better than the house, then you could devise an optimal betting strategy in some cases but not all. Again, the vig protects the casino from losing money to "sharps" who do, on occasion, have more information to work with.

Comment: In general, the best way to estimate the probabilities of events based on the listed odds (O1, O2 and O3 in this case) is to do the following: Calculate Q1 = 1/(1 + O1), Q2 = 1/(1 + O2) and Q3 = 1/(1 + O3). Then, calculate P1 = Q1/(Q1 + Q2 + Q3), P2 = Q2/(Q1 + Q2 + Q3) and P3 = Q3/(Q1 + Q2 + Q3). P1, P2 and P3 are the best-guess probabilities of events 1, 2 and 3, respectively. Unfortunately, in your case, if you base your bets off these probabilities, then your expected return will be negative no matter how you bet your money.